Google sheets IMPORTXML and XPath href and title not returned
I need to extract some URLS and their respective titles using Google Sheets ImportXML with Xpath.
I found these previous answers and tested them but they don't seem to be working for my case:
Extract URL using xpath
How do I return a specific link address using IMPORTXML and XPath
I tested these formulas:
=IMPORTXML("https://ok.ru/video/334044074277","//*[contains(@class, 'video-card_n-w')]//a/@href", "en_US")
=IMPORTXML("https://ok.ru/video/334044074277","//*[contains(@class, 'video-card_n-w')]/a/@title", "en_US")
href returns #.
The xpaths seems correct on chrome developer tool.
EDIT1: title works now but not href.
EDIT2:
I tested this also but same # result:
=IMPORTXML("https://ok.ru/video/334044074277","//*[contains(@class, 'video-card_n ellip')]/@href", "en_US").

this is the collection page test with same output:
=IMPORTXML("https://ok.ru/video/c1458725","//*[contains(@class, 'video-card_n ellip')]/@href", "en_US")

I just tesed with firefox and it has the # for the href:
https://i.imgur.com/gqiun3J.png
I'll test with data-id.
Ok, data-id is working =IMPORTXML("https://ok.ru/video/c1458725","//*[contains(@class, 'video-card js-movie-card')]/@data-id", "en_US")

would this satisfy you? https://i.sstatic.net/HlFJ5p7O.png

Wow, you rock as always @player0! Amazing, overdelivering! That was exactly what I was looking for the end result! Would you please share it as the answer and I'll gladly accept it! be well!

if you run:
=IMPORTXML("https://ok.ru/video/c1458725","//@href")


you can see why are you getting #

try:
=INDEX(LET(x, "https://ok.ru", HYPERLINK(x&QUERY(
 IMPORTXML(x&"/video/c1458725","//@href", "en_US"), "where Col1 matches '/video.*album'", ), 
 IMPORTXML(x&"/video/c1458725","//*[contains(@class, 'video-card_n ellip')]"))))



Great thanks a lot! I'll study it next with Let and Index. Be well!

Hi @player0! I think this comment got deleted not sure why.
Is there a way to extend the output to larger than 24 hyperlinks with your formula? Because I found some case with larger than 24 urls and the formula don't return the remainder ones. For instance this one: =INDEX(LET(x, "https://ok.ru", HYPERLINK(x&QUERY(  IMPORTXML(x&"/video/c719620","//@href", "en_US"), "where Col1 matches '/video.*album'", ),   IMPORTXML(x&"/video/c719620","//*[contains(@class, 'video-card_n ellip')]"))))

@Lod it depends from case to case. hard to tell like this.

Ok, the output should return 78 urls for this c719620 inpput. Is the limit to 24 due to google sheets? Can't this be solved with a formula instead of a script?

@Lod not really google sheets limit but IMPORTXML limit as it cant see further. in this case I would suggest script solution of some kind
